# Unable to connect to docker container at server from client machine

Tags: docker

As title.  I want to test the new structure of the web application,  so I made some projects and published onto DOCKER on the server,  I cannot connect from my client machine. But on the contrary, When I created the same docker container at client-side, I could connect that from my server machine.

About my situation:

1. OS of the client side and server side are Windows;
2. Image inside the docker Containers is built in the client machine, saved as TAR file, and moved to server to load onto the docker.
3. The image is developed from an ASP.NET CORE WEB API project developed using the VS2022 and .Net 8.0
4. The firewall is set to allow the connection through the 2 certain ports.
5. Docker Desktop is available for my client machine but not for the server, the server and only operate docker via CMD or The Powershell.
6. Neither client-side or server-side could install Nginx.
7. It's OK to switch to Linux mode at client-side but not in the server-side because of the lack of DockerCli.exe

Could someone guide me to solve this problem?